# What are some concrete applications of Grothendieck's six operations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

In Gallauer's *An introduction to six-functor formalisms* I read:

> Indeed, the language and theory of six-functor formalisms permeates much of modern algebraic geometry and beyond, and has spawned entire fields of research. The development of, for example, étale cohomology, perverse sheaves, or motivic homotopy theory is quite unthinkable in the absence of the six operations.

If the development of étale cohomology is unthinkable in the absence of the six operations, why aren't they mentioned in Milne's lecture notes on étale cohomology or the book of Freitag and Kiehl?

Which theorems in étale cohomology need (or benefit from) the six operations in its proof? What are some concrete theorems that can be proved with the six operations?

Comment: Five of the six operations are certainly mentioned in Milne or Freitag and Kiehl, maybe not under that name though. They are just pullback, pushforward, tensor product, internal hom and direct image with compact support, The other appears whenever one wants to talk about general duality theorems ("Grothendieck=Verdier duality") and is implicit in the discussion in Freitag and Kiehl as well... The six functor formalism is just the construction of these six functors together with some of their properties (projection formula, Poincaré duality, purity, etc.)

Comment: @DenisNardin So the six operations formalism is just an axiomatization of properties that a 6-tuple of functors might or might not satisfy? Where can I read a concise definition of these axioms? What theorems can be deduced from these axioms? Where can I find a reference checking that etale cohomology satisfies these axioms? (Then one would be able to draw the theorems as formal consequences.)

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer, but for a concise definition of what a six functor formalism is I recommend A.5 in Cisinski-Déglise ["Triangulated categories of mixed motives"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2110)

Comment: Grothendieck was interested in a "complete" and general theory of cohomology, taking account of all the usual phenomena in the most general setting possible (the natural context where the notions have essential meaning, leaving concrete issues aside for later). Thus, his discovery of étale cohomology led him immediately to unveil a general formalism of derived categories. Meanwhile, most other mathematicians were primarily interested in the Weil Conject.(the applications of étale cohomology), and so, they gave less importance to the general "philosophy" (yoga) that inspired the development.